# how to make a part of the textbox as readonly

Tags: c#, javascript

i have a tagtextbox on my page
when a user selects a category that category name goes to tagtextbox

now i want that this category name user cant change but he can append some more tags
means first tag becomes readonly and further he can add too in same text box

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

Instead, you can put the first category name in a `<span>`, and put the textbox after the span.
You can then apply `border: none` to the textbox and make your own border around the entire thing to make it look like a single textbox.

Answer (score 2):

**CSS :**

```
<style type="text/css">
.div {
   margin:20px; 
   padding:10px; 
   background:#ccc; 
   float:left;
}

.textarea {
   border:0; 
   display:block; 
   font-size:12px; 
   padding:5px 5px 0; 
   outline:none; 
}

.span {
   display:block;
   background:#fff;
   font-size:14px;  
   padding:5px 5px 5px; 
   color:green; 
   outline:none;
}
</style>
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="div">
<div class="span">
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNumber" BorderStyle="None" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ValidationExpression="\d+" ControlToValidate="txtNumber" ErrorMessage="Only Numbers are allowed" Display="Dynamic" />
</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: I am unable to post the full answer.The HTMl part is not displaying in the answer.even if I am trying to edit the answer, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Check it now for the edit's in your answer i have formatted in a correct manner.
Note : Use the basic attribute element's in stack overflow editor to design or formatting your answer.
Example : 
For Bold The Text ---> Use Ctrl + B
For Italic The Text ---> Use Ctrl + I
For Code Sample Block ---> Use Ctrl + K

Answer (score 0):

You can't make part of a textbox editable and another not.

My suggestion would be to change the type of element from a TextBox to a div or span via Javascript as soon as the user begins to enter the next tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow append has in "paste" action, then you can't do that. Else and you just want to append via your code, why not use just a div to show what he has selected and add the selections to your post on a hidden textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what SLaks said - Here is an example of a CSS & HTML hack where someone has added a **span** under the **textbox**. To make it look like it is part of the same textbox there is a border round the enclosing div. It looks quite effective.

[textbox with uneditable name at the bottom](http://jsfiddle.net/WbSms/1/)